# How to pass this function into settimeout with parameters?

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout

```
var test = function(a, b) {   return a + b; }; 
setTimeout(test(2, 3), 3000);
```

it shows some type error

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two ways to achieve this.
The first one just fires the `test` function inside of a new anonymous function passed as callback to the `setTimout`.

The second one uses `.bind` to partially apply the `test` function.

```js
var test = function(a, b) {
  console.log(a + b);
  return a + b;
};

setTimeout(() => {
  test(2, 3);
}, 3000);

setTimeout(test.bind(null, 2, 3), 3000);
```

And if you don't like the first (in this case meaningless) argument `null` of `.bind` as I do, then you can use some library that provides you with partial application functionality or you can write your own function that performs partial application.

```js
const partial = (fn, ...firstArgs) => (...secondArgs) =>
  fn(...firstArgs, ...secondArgs);

var test = function(a, b) {
  console.log(a + b);
  return a + b;
};

setTimeout(partial(test, 2, 3), 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way to call an external function inside setTimeout

```
var  test = function(a, b) { return a + b; };     
setTimeout(function() {test(2, 3)} , 3000)
```

Comment: You have enough rep to flag to close the question as duplicate. Please don't post an answer when you are aware that there is a duplicate question with answers much better than yours available.